# filtering data with timezone- SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, database, filter, sqlalchemy

The Code is not filtering data with timezone. It is filtering data based on the datetime object values.

I am trying to imrove the filter function so that different it can filter data with timezone.

[image]

Query:

```
records = session.query(MyTable).filter(
  MyTable.created_at == pytz.timezone(
    'US/Eastern').localize(datetime.datetime(2025, 1, 1, 11, 0))
    ).all()

# Print the records
print("\nPrinting Record : \n")
for record in records:
    print(record.id, record.created_at)
```

Code is:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column 
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, ForeignKey, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import datetime
import pytz

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///mydatabase12.db', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

# Creating table over Base
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime(timezone=True))


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# Creating Session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

#Inserting Data with Timezone in the table

# Create a new record with a DateTime value of January 1st, 
# 2024 at 10:00 AM in the US/Eastern timezone
created_at = pytz.timezone(
  'US/Eastern').localize(datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 10, 0))
record = MyTable(created_at=created_at)
session.add(record)
session.commit()
# Create a new record with a DateTime value of January 1st, 
# 2024 at 11:00 AM in the UTC timezone
created_at = pytz.timezone(
  'UTC').localize(datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 11, 0))
record = MyTable(created_at=created_at)
session.add(record)
session.commit()
# Create a new record with a DateTime value of January 1st, 
# 2024 at 12:00 AM in the US/Eastern timezone
created_at = pytz.timezone(
  'US/Eastern').localize(datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 12, 0))
record = MyTable(created_at=created_at)
session.add(record)
session.commit()
```

first i tried this:

```
# Specify the timezone you want to filter records by
target_timezone = 'US/Eastern'

# Specify the datetime you want to filter records by (already localized to the target timezone)
target_datetime = pytz.timezone(target_timezone).localize(datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 10, 0))

# Query for all records in the table that have a DateTime value equal to the target datetime in the target timezone
records = session.query(MyTable).filter(
    func.timezone(target_timezone, MyTable.created_at) == target_datetime
).all()
```

But it gave error sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: timezone  because timezone is not supported by SQLite.
Then, I tried using strftime but the query is not able to find any record. Records is empty even if it exists in table.

```
# Specify the timezone you want to filter records by
target_timezone = 'US/Eastern'

# Specify the datetime you want to filter records by (already localized to the target timezone)
target_datetime = pytz.timezone(target_timezone).localize(datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 10, 0))

# Query for all records in the table that have a DateTime value equal to the target datetime in the target timezone
records = session.query(MyTable).filter(
    func.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', 'localtime', MyTable.created_at) == target_datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
).all()
```

I also tried filtering using python.But the filtered records still remains empty. When I print datetime values stored in table, it does not contain timezone info. strftime("%Z") return None.

```
# Specify the timezone you want to filter records by
target_timezone = 'US/Eastern'

# Specify the datetime you want to filter records by (already localized to the target timezone)
target_datetime = pytz.timezone(target_timezone).localize(datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 1, 10, 0))

# Retrieve all records from the table
all_records = session.query(MyTable).all()

# Filter the records by checking if the created_at datetime in the target timezone is equal to the target datetime
filtered_records = [
    record for record in all_records
    if record.created_at.astimezone(pytz.timezone(target_timezone)) == target_datetime
]

# Print the filtered records
print("\nPrinting Record : \n")
for record in filtered_records:
    print(record.id, record.created_at)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't have built-in support for time zones (see [2.2. Date and Time Datatype](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)) but you can use time zones with SQLAlchemy and SQLite by storing dates and times in the database as UTC. Then, when you want to read the dates and times from the database, you can convert them back to the desired time zone using Python library pytz.

Here's a simple example:

First, you need to create a custom data type called UTCDateTime:

```
import datetime
import pytz
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, DateTime

class UTCDateTime(TypeDecorator):
    impl = DateTime

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            return value.astimezone(pytz.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z')

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z').astimezone(pytz.utc)
```

Then, use that UTCDateTime type in tables e.g.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///example.db')

class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_at = Column(UTCDateTime)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Now, when you store dates and times in the created_at column, they will be stored as UTC. When you read them from the database, they will be converted back to the desired time zone.

---

Here's and end-to-end demonstration you should be able to run locally (sadly I don't know of any fiddle site that support pytz) as a proof of concept:

```
pip install sqlalchemy pytz
```

Then:

```
import datetime
import pytz
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, DateTime

class UTCDateTime(TypeDecorator):
    impl = DateTime

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            return value.astimezone(pytz.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z')

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if value is not None:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z').astimezone(pytz.utc)

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///example.db')

class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_at = Column(UTCDateTime)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Insert a new row with the current time in a specific timezone
now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("America/New_York"))
new_entry = MyModel(created_at=now)
session.add(new_entry)
session.commit()

# Retrieve the row and display the stored datetime
stored_entry = session.query(MyModel).first()
print("Stored datetime:", stored_entry.created_at)

# Convert the stored datetime to a different timezone and display it
converted_datetime = stored_entry.created_at.astimezone(pytz.timezone("Asia/Tokyo"))
print("Converted datetime:", converted_datetime)
```